# Find a linear cost function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

First, I can find a cost function where fixed cost is involved.

- Eight units cost $\$300$; fixed cost is $\$60$.

I got $C(x)= 30x + 60$

However, for a problem like

- Twelve units cost $\$445$; $50$ units cost $\$1585$.

I don't think my solution process is right. I get the slope like always, which is $30$, and create the $C(x)$ from one of the points
\begin{align*}
p-445 & = 30(q-12)\\
p-445 & = 30q-360\\
p & = 30q + 85\\
C(x)& = 30x+85
\end{align*}

Now, the solution says the function I've created is wrong.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your solution is correct.  There is an error in the solution key.

Answer (score 1):

For the second,

Slope should be $\frac{1585-445}{50-12}=\frac{1140}{38}=\$30$ per unit.

Now point slope, $p-445=30(q-12)$

$p-445=30q-360$

$p=30q+85$

$C(x)=30x+85$

Your solution seems fine to me.

Comment: For the first one, we have a slope of $$\frac{300 - 60}{8} = \frac{240}{8} = 30$$  You forgot to take into account the fixed costs.

Comment: Oops! @taussig haha